# Mapbox not displaying navigation controls in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-js

I'm using React.js 15.3.1 and Mapbox GL 0.23.0.

I want to display [navigation controls in my map](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/navigation/), but it's not showing up.

Here's my code:

```
class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    mapboxgl.accessToken = MAPBOX_TOKEN;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: 'map',
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v9',
      center: [20, 40],
      zoom: 1.2,
    });

    map.addControl(new mapboxgl.Navigation());
  }

  render() {
    return <div id="map" style={styles} />;
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you receiving any console error / using react dev tools?

Comment: @Kilmazing no errors =/

Comment: I have almost the exact same code